# Generate a list of rules from two rules

Tags: list-manipulation, replacement

I have two lists:

```
a = {a1,a2,a3}
b = {b1,b2,b3}
```

and I want to generate a list of replacement rules

```
r = {a1->b1,a2->b2,a3->b3}
```

I would have thought I could simply do

```
r = #1->#2&/@[a,b]
```

But this produces no output. This is such a simple operation I'm sure there's something very straightforward. I could of couse use a `Table`, but I'm sure there's an easy and elegant method I'm missing.

Comment: Because `/@` is `Map` , so one way is to `#1->#2&[a,b]` , but is not what you want. `(#[[1]] -> #[[2]] &) /@ {{a1, a2}, {b1, b2}}` partly works.Not elegant. So you may want this `(#[[1]] -> #[[2]] &) /@Transpose@ {a, b}`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Thread[ a -> b]
```

> ```
>  {a1 -> b1, a2 -> b2, a3 -> b3}
> ```

Also:

```
Inner[Rule, a, b, List]
```

> ```
>  {a1 -> b1, a2 -> b2, a3 -> b3}
> ```

and

```
# -> #2 & @@@ Transpose[{a, b}]
```

> ```
>  {a1 -> b1, a2 -> b2, a3 -> b3}
> ```

```
Rule @@@ Transpose[{a, b}]
```

> ```
>  {a1 -> b1, a2 -> b2, a3 -> b3}
> ```